# Prevent Sass from including property at all

Tags: html, css, sass, mixins

In my current project I use a **sass-mixin** roughly like this:

**mixin.scss:**

```
@mixin my_mixin($header-border-top-stack, 
                $header-border-bottom-stack) {
  #some-id {
     border-top: $header-border-top-stack;
     border-bottom: $header-border-top-stack;
  }
}
```

**styles.scss:**

```
@import "path/to/mixin.scss";
@include my_mixin(1px solid black, 2px solid red);
```

Sometimes I don't want to touch the `border-bottom` property at all. 
Sadly this:

```
@import "path/to/mixin.scss";
@include my_mixin(1px solid black, none);
```

results in `.css` like this:

```
#some-id {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

I'm looking for a way to prevent the mixing from touching the `border-bottom` property at all (don't even include it in the `.css`). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an `@if condition` for the check

```
@mixin my_mixin($header-border-top-stack, $header-border-bottom-stack) {
  #some-id {
    border-top: $header-border-top-stack;
    @if $header-border-bottom-stack != 'none' {
      border-bottom: $header-border-bottom-stack;
    }
  }
}
```

This works fine. However just a tip, I noticed that you're `mixin` places the selector inside it which isn't flexible and I don't know if that's good practice. You could rewrite it this way

```
@mixin my_mixin($header-border-top-stack, $header-border-bottom-stack) {
  border-top: $header-border-top-stack;
  @if $header-border-bottom-stack != 'none' {
    border-bottom: $header-border-bottom-stack;
  }
}
```

By doing this you're `mixin` can be used on different `tags`
`div { @include my_mixin(1px solid black, none); }`
`p { @include my_mixin(1px solid black, 2px solid red); }`

instead of it always returning `#some-id { ... }`

Comment: Thank you really much! I'll stick with the `id` inside the `mixin` though. The purpose of this `mixin` is just to generate a chunk of code depending on some variables, so i can use slightly different designs in `@media-queries` :) The `border`-property was just an example, an in reality I use it to control the width of a `div` in different `media-queries`.